# Silverlight client doesn't connect to server

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, deployment, wcf-ria-services

I just deployed a Silverlight app.

It's an authenticated app (i.e. only logged-in users may access it, otherwise navigates to the login screen), I launch the application, I can see the Silverlight interface loading and forwarding to the login screen, but even I enter a un/pwd that exists in the server, it doesn't let me get in.

I tried throwing an exception from the `AuthenticationService.GetUser` (RIA), but I don't see any sign of exception on the client.

Can you think of something I missed out while deploying?

On my development environment it works great, it just doesn't get to work on the server.

**Update**

Note, I navigated to http://localhost/project-authenticationservice.svc and a similar page is rendered to my browser:

[image]

Comment: I highly recommend Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to help debug things like that. It will show all requests your app is doing, so you can see if is trying to hit the right server/url

Comment: @Leo, +1, but I am trying to avoid installing software on that machine.

Comment: If you can't install Fiddler you can use IE9 or Chromes developer tools. They show you the network traffic and anything logged to the console (in the browser).

Comment: Are you using a custom ClientCodeGenerator to generate the silverlight client code? Then may help you my question on silverlight.net http://forums.silverlight.net/t/243278.aspx/1?Endpoint+not+found+for+deployed+WCF+Ria+Service+with+custom+ClientCodeGenerator

Comment: @Jehof, nope, no custom generators (except for Entity-Framework model generator).

Comment: Do you tried to enabled WCF Tracing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx to get more information whats going on?

Comment: I just enabled it, I can now see the errors, but don't know what it is or what is its source, will update my question.

Comment: @Jehof, although I already did this myself, you can post it as an answer and I will mark it so you gain rep, as soon as I was able to trace the error, I realized it's the database that resides in the App_Data folder that is inaccessible, [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/fbf32aa8-2125-4919-be81-3baa399e2e0d#7ae83972-64a5-41d4-ae9d-55f40d8cea69) solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really could be caused b any number of reasons. Ensure that your service endpoints have been updated correctly to reflect the server environment. Also, here are some helpful troubleshooting tips when deploying a Silverlight app with a RIA service.

Check out [this](http://todormihailov.com/2010/12/03/silverilght-with-net-4-0-wcf-ria-services-and-iis-error-notfound-%E2%80%93-a-deploy-nightmare) blog post.

And here is a video that details some more deployment and debugging tips when deploying WCF RIA services: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Silverlight-TV-51-Debugging-and-Deploying-WCF-RIA-Services

Google Chrome has a nice set of developer tools that allow you to monitor the http network traffic that could help you as well.

Comment: How can I ensure that? I debugged it on my IDE and worked, I then copied the same debug DLLs that worked on the dev machine to the server and it doesn't work, as per the link, in my case, I don't even get an exception, it just doesn't show anything but the normal UI invalid-credentials message.

Comment: There is no such file in the XAP. Any other ways to overcome this issue. I need to make this program work on the server. Anyway, I've updated my question, please take a look.